# Android Terminal error (file 64-Bit ELF)

Tags: terminal

So, I need to have the program 'objdump' on my phone thought I can just copy it from my Linux box to my phone and everything will be fine. But after I copied it with adb in the terminal it says

```
sh: /system/bin/objdump: not executable: 64-bit ELF file
```

What I have tried:

```
chmod 755 /system/bin/objdump
```

But that doesn't seem to fix the problem. Please help.

Comment: Without knowing your phone model and brand, we cannot know its architecture, either. My answer, while generic, will be a good starting point for you to search for more information. Remember that compiling software and other development concerns are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I recommend you install Termux and then install g++ from there and use its binaries instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot just reuse the same binaries on both a computer and a mobile device, as the processors of the abovementioned are likely to differ.

In your case, you are trying to run an `objdump` binary compiled for a 64-bit processor on a device which is most certainly powered by an ARM processor. The processor of your Android device cannot understand the instructions used within the binary, and thus rejects the file.

In order to ultimately run the binary, you need to obtain its source code, discern your Android device's processor architecture and build `objdump` from source against the given architecture.